# parsing HTML in Knockout.JS from a JS method

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm attaching a method to add a class to a date, but in knockout, it's showing the actual HTML. I am new to knockout, so any ideas welcome. It outputs the attached. Any ideas? Thanks

here's the HTML

```
<div class="item">
 <h3><?=l(672)?></h3>
    <p data-bind="text:order().campaign_end_date"></p>
</div>
```

// Knockout code

```
  this.campaign_end_date = 
  ax.Utils.campaignEndDateAlert(data.campaign_end_date);
```

//JS Part which adds the span

```
    publicMethods.campaignEndDateAlert = function (dateString) {
     if (!dateString) {return dateString};
     var currentDate = new Date ();
     var twoWeeks = new Date ();
     twoWeeks.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 14);
     var inputDate = new Date(dateString);

     if ( (inputDate >= currentDate) && (inputDate <= twoWeeks) ) { 
      dateString = '<span class="red">' + dateString + '</span>';
    }
  return dateString;
};
```

[image: <span class="red">2017-07-05</span>]

Comment: Try changing the binding from "text" to "html". `<p data-bind="html:order().campaign_end_date"></p>`

Comment: The `html` binding should work, as @Jason said.  Having said that, one wonders why you're manually building html fragments when you're already using something capable of doing templating.

Comment: Thanks Jason! How silly and easy

Comment: hey James, you're right but without going into details that will bore you to tears, it's just the way we have to do it right now :)